# Linking to image in a local directory vs. URL, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, xaml

In xaml if have the following:

```
 <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image/somehing.png"/>
```

And use that to create an image it works fine, but if I do it as follows:

```
 <Setter Property="Source" Value="AnASPXPage.aspx"/>
```

and inside the page I do:

```
 Response.Redirect("Image/somehing.png");
```

It doesn't work.

But if I link to an image online, i.e.:

```
  Response.Redirect("url.com/Image/somehing.png");
```

It works fine.

how can I make it so that I can link to a local image directory from the aspx page?

Comment: Maybe is a problem in the directory levels ? for example do you have try Response.Redirect("/Image/somehing.png"); - with the slash on front ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your directory structure, but "~" in front of your path will resolve to the root of your application whether a root site or virtual directory.

```
Response.Redirect("~Image/somehing.png");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("~/Image/somehing.png");
```